# Objectify Add entity to root within transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

My question is quite simple.

I have User instances which don't belong to any parent and as such their entity group is root. I want to add them inside a transaction with Objectify.
The problem is that I don't know how to tell objectify that User parent is root and when I do multiple put(User) I get:

```
   operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction
```

Should I add some kind of special @Parent to User?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a cross-group transaction
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions

Comment: It already is considered a cross-group transaction and as such I can only "affect" 5 different entity groups. Now my issue is that it should be only one entity group..."root"...right?

Comment: no, each entity is its own root.  you're right that it's a cross group transaction, but do you have the correct syntax to indicate that it's a cross group transaction?

Comment: Many sorries for the delaied repply and thanks for the atention...I simply did a put within a transaction and the commit...for what I could understand objectify detects it's more then one entity group and does cross group transaction under the hood. Nevertheless, if I put 4 entities everything works fine but if I do it with 5 I get the described error. 
So is there any way to put more then 5 entities whose parent is root within a transaction?